# Neural network categorization: Do they always have to have one label per training data

Tags: neural-network, training-data, categorization

In all the examples of categorization with neural networks that I have seen, they all have training data that has one category as the predominant category or the label for each input data.

Can you feed training data that has more than one label. Eg: a picture with a "cat" and a "mouse".

I understand (maybe wrong) that if you use softmax for probability/prediction at the output layer, it tends to try and select one (maximize discerning power). I'm guessing this would hurt/prevent learning and predicting multiple labels with input data.

Is there any approach/architecture of NN where there are multiple labels in training data and multiple outputs predictions are made ? or is that already the case and I missed some vital understanding. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most examples have one class per input, so no you haven't missed anything. It is however possible to do multi-class classification, which is sometimes called joint classification in the literature.

The naive implementation you suggested with a softmax will struggle as the outputs on the final layer have to add up to 1, so the more classes you have the harder it is to figure out what the network is trying to say.

You can change the architecture to achieve what you want however. For each class you could have a binary softmax classifier which branches off from the penultimate layer <s>or you can use a sigmoid, which doesn't have to add up to one (even though each neuron outputs between 0 and 1). Note using a sigmoid might make training more difficult.</s>

Alternatively you could train multiple networks for each class and then combine them into one classification system at the end. It depends on how complex your envisioned task is.

Comment: binary softmax and 'unary' sigmoid is pretty much the same thing, and using sigmoid in the output will not make things any harder.

Comment: Thank you Luka, your explanation was clear and helpful. However, one point remains. My intuition is the same as @lejlot since there are only two possibilities (yes/no). Can you clarify why you think softmax would make it easier or conversely why sigmoid would make it harder ? Prior literature or experimental data?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any approach/architecture of NN where there are multiple labels in training data and multiple outputs predictions are made ?

Answer is YES. To briefly answer your question, I am giving an example in the context of [Keras](https://keras.io/), a high-level neural network library.

Let's consider the following model. We want to predict how many retweets and likes a news headline will receive on Twitter. The main input to the model will be the headline itself, as a sequence of words, but to spice things up, our model will also have an auxiliary input, receiving extra data such as the time of day when the headline was posted, etc.

[image]

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, merge
from keras.models import Model

# headline input: meant to receive sequences of 100 integers, between 1 and 10000.
# note that we can name any layer by passing it a "name" argument.
main_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')

# this embedding layer will encode the input sequence
# into a sequence of dense 512-dimensional vectors.
x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(main_input)

# a LSTM will transform the vector sequence into a single vector,
# containing information about the entire sequence
lstm_out = LSTM(32)(x)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = merge([lstm_out, auxiliary_input], mode='concat')

# we stack a deep fully-connected network on top
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

# and finally we add the main logistic regression layer
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)
```

This defines a model with two inputs and two outputs:

```
model = Model(input=[main_input, auxiliary_input], output=[main_output, auxiliary_output])
```

Now, lets compile and train the model as follows:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})

# and trained it via:
model.fit({'main_input': headline_data, 'aux_input': additional_data},
          {'main_output': labels, 'aux_output': labels},
          nb_epoch=50, batch_size=32)
```

Reference: [Multi-input and multi-output models in Keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models)

Comment: I appreciate the detail and the flow diagram Wasi. Kindly clarify if your headline input was such that it allowed a max of 100 words, and each word was indexed to a number between 1 and 10,000 ? Is that the encoding ?

Comment: @SriramGopalakrishnan yes, that will be the input but there is an embedding layer which will convert the words to lower dimension.